# What does an HTTP server send to client when the socket is to be closed?

Tags: http, webserver

As per title. I've been google'ing extensively and found nothing. I've tried the RFC definition of HTTP/1.1, however it is a quite cubersome document. Does the server send anything? (now is a good time to mention that I want to use persistant connections?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTTP/1.1 persistent connections, the connection may be kept open after a request, typically for a few seconds.  Once some time has passed, the TCP connection is simply closed.  No messages or anything are sent.  None are needed.

You can easily see this yourself if you fire up a packet sniffer, like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).